# How can I register with 2 categories of users and save the status in the database?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, project

This is what my current code looks like, but the status is not saved in the database. Even if in models I default = 'Admin' in the database it appears at status: '-'. Why?
I want to add the status to the database to know which category users belong to

models.py

```
STATUS_CHOICES = Choices(
    ('Client', 'Client'),
    ('Master', 'Master')
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(error_messages={
        'unique': 'A user is already registered with this email!'},
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    confirmed_password = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, verbose_name='confirmed_password')
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='status', default="Admin")
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

forms.py

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('email', 'password', 'confirmed_password', 'username')
```

views.py

```
def RegisterUser(request):
    master = EditUserForm(request.POST)
    if request.POST:
        if master.is_valid() and request.POST["status"] == "Master":
            master.save()
            messages.success(request, "It was successfully registered master")

            return render(request, "registration/index.html")
        elif master.is_valid() and request.POST["status"] == "Client":
            master.save()
            messages.success(request, "It was successfully registered CLIENT")

            return render(request, "registration/index.html")
        else:
            return render(request, "registration/register.html", {})
    else:
        master = EditUserForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {'master': master})
```

register.html

```
 <h1>Registration Page</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ master.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="status" value="Master" />
    <input type="submit" name="status" value="Client" />
</form>
```

Comment: I did not see any place where you save status of user

Comment: and how do I save the user's status?

Comment: How is defined your AbstractUser ?

Comment: I used AbstractUser to have the user table and I added / modified some fields according to preference. (User table generated by Django as an example has no status, confirm password)

Comment: Did you get one of your messages ?

Comment: if you refer to the messages in the views, the answer is yes, I receive them.